# Distributed Computing and the wEB

Tags: web, distributed-computing

Is Web App considered distributed computing ?
My reasoning would say yes, because the computing is distributed between machines at different physical locations and a network is required.

But i think most people considers distributed computing as strictly parallel, whereas webapps don't run in parallel ... they run sequentially.

So, could Web Apps be considered as a serial kind of distributed computing, or distributed computing is strictly parallel ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: wEB? you mean *web*.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Web Applications are distributed computing.

You have `User View`, `Applicaion Tier` and the `Database`. Also called as 3-tier architecture.

User view is where you have the `UI` or he `frontend`. `Application tier` is where you have your business logic and then you have the database. They can be be on three different systems.

Of course, sometimes, the application and the database are present on the same system, in this case its a 2-tier architecture, but is still distributed.

[Three tier architecture](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/dbms/dbms_architecture.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily identify a distributed system, because it will randomly crash because a machine you don't even need has given up the ghost.

In the most simple instance of a Web App, you have two "tiers": The application server and the user's browser (or whatever client is used to access the application; one could argue that the client is not part of the system, thus it would not be distributed).

Most web apps at least talk to a database, and unless it's in in-process DB (like H2 or Sqlite), you most certainly have another tier. Now we have the start of a distributed system.

So in short: It depends. Most Web Apps *are* distributed, but it's not a given.